# Functor declaration with multiple types?

Tags: haskell, functor

I've got the following data type:

```
data Users id height weight = User id height weight

instance Functor Users where
fmap f (User id height weight) = User(f id height weight)
```

Yet this won't compile?

It works fine when I use a type with a single parameter, such as:

```
data Users id = User id
instance Functor Users where
fmap f (User id) = User (f id)
```

Why isn't my first example working?

Comment: The second example doesn't do what you think - you need indentation on `fmap` to make it part of the instance.  The first example you omitted the error which tells you the issue (n.b. It's an issue of kinds, functor instances are of kind `*->*`).

Comment: `Yet this won't compile?` What is the compiler error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each type and type constructor has a kind. Something simple like `Int` has kind `*`. Your single-argument type constructor `Users` has kind `* -> *`; it takes one type and returns a new one. Your first example of `Users` has kind `* -> * -> * -> *`; it takes *three* types and returns a new one.

`Functor` only works with type constructors of kind `* -> *`. This allows you to define a `Functor` instance for your second `Users` type constructor, but not your first one.

Think about your first try: the data constructor `Users` takes three arguments, but your definition of `fmap` attempts to call it with just one, the return value of f. You could make `Users` a functor as long as you are willing to make all three fields the same type:

```
data Users a = Users a a a

instance Functor Users where
    fmap f (Users a b c) = Users (f a) (f b) (f c)
```

In theory, you could define a class `Trifunctor` (there is a `Bifunctor` class available):

```
class Trifunctor f where
    trimap :: (a1 -> b1) -> (a2 -> b2) -> (a3 -> b3) -> f a1 a2 a3 -> f b1 b2 b3

data Users a b c = Users a b c

instance Trifunctor Users where
    trimap f g h (Users a b c) = Users (f a) (g b) (h c)
```

but it's debatable how useful this would be. `Functor` is useful for general purpose containers, because they have a wide range of uses. `Users`, on the other hand, seems pretty specific. You generally don't need the flexibility you are defining it with; `data User = User Int Int Int` seems like it would work fine, and there is no need to map a function over this: how often to you need the same function to modify height, weight, and age in the same way?

Comment: So is there anyway of applying a functor to my first example?

Comment: See my last update: what function do you envision being useful to apply to a user's height, weight, *and* age?

Comment: Thanks - its not really a case of 'useful', more of trying to get to grips with what functions/applicative functors can do and where they can be useful...

Answer (score 2):

Instances of the `Functor` class can be defined for types of first-order kind only, which are those of kind `* -> *`

If you try querying GHCI as follows

```
ghci> :kind Users
Users :: * -> * -> * -> *
```

you will understand that you custom type is of much higher kindness, hence the compiler error.

If you still wish to provide an instance of the `Functor` class for it, despite how useful that could be, do as follows

```
ghci> :{
    | -- define custom type having a too high kind
    | data User a b c = User a b c deriving Show
    |
    | -- provide functor instance by reducing its type kindness 
    | instance Functor (User a b) where
    |   fmap f (User x y z) = User x y (f z)
    | :}
```

The trick is to **partially** apply the `User` type constructor so to produce a type having kindness reduced to the expected one. Then, define your `fmap` by pattern matching the whole `User` value constructor and apply the function `f` to the last input value.

Example of usage is:

```
ghci> u1 = User 1 168 58.9
ghci> fmap (+5) u1
User 1 168 63.9
```

That's roughly how the `Either`, tuple `(,)` and function `(->)` types, which are also higher-order kinded types in Haskell prelude, are able to provide instances of the `Functor` class too.